# CSS3 bending/perspective effect

Tags: html, css

For example, I have such a picture:
[image: Default image]

And I need to make it like that with CSS3. With a kind of perspective in the top (area marked with red border):
[image: Image with perspective]

Is it even possible to make such an effect using only 1 image and CSS3 styles?

Comment: You should be using a projection for this to work—what about using pre-existing libraries such as d3.js? It has various projections that help you to resolve the issue of distorted land area around polar regions. A pure CSS fix is only a workaround and a stop-gap solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set a div with your image as background.

On a pseudo element, the same background, and this pseudo has a transform of rotation and perspective.

Another pseudo, in the same position, to mask the upper part of the original  image

```css
.test {
  width: 600px;
  height: 230px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ1Bp.png);
  background-size: 600px 230px;
  position: relative;
}
.test:after,
.test:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.test:before {
  background-color: white;
}
.test:after {
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: inherit;
  border: solid 1px green;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(50deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```